# csv files in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been reading in csv format data into Pandas and it puts the date column header into the data.

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\WTISPLC.csv", 
     index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
print(s1)
```

running this gives me:

```
            WTISPLC
DATE               
1946-01-01     1.17
1946-02-01     1.17
1946-03-01     1.17
1946-04-01     1.27
1946-05-01     1.27
```

Comment: what is your question? what were you hoping to get from your code?

Comment: what is your problem? You didn't ask question. And what result did you expect?

Comment: Header `DATE` is not in data - it only shows that column `DATE` is used as `index` instead of row's numbers. Maybe if you remove `index_col=0` then it will use `DATE` as normal column. Or you can use `s1 = s1.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Header `DATE` is not in data - `pandas` only shows that now column `DATE` is used as `index` instead of row's numbers.

If you remove `index_col=0` then it will use `DATE` as normal column.

Or you can use `df = df.reset_index()` after loading.

---

Minimal working code

```
text = '''
DATE,WTISPLC
1946-01-01,1.17
1946-02-01,1.17
1946-03-01,1.17
1946-04-01,1.27
1946-05-01,1.27
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print(df)
print('---')
print(df.columns)
print(df.index)

print('\n--- index_col=0 ----\n')

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), index_col=0)
print(df)
print('---')
print(df.columns)
print(df.index)

print('\n--- reset_index() ---\n')

df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
print('---')
print(df.columns)
print(df.index)
```

Result:

```
         DATE  WTISPLC
0  1946-01-01     1.17
1  1946-02-01     1.17
2  1946-03-01     1.17
3  1946-04-01     1.27
4  1946-05-01     1.27
---
Index(['DATE', 'WTISPLC'], dtype='object')
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)

--- index_col=0 ----

            WTISPLC
DATE               
1946-01-01     1.17
1946-02-01     1.17
1946-03-01     1.17
1946-04-01     1.27
1946-05-01     1.27
---
Index(['WTISPLC'], dtype='object')
Index(['1946-01-01', '1946-02-01', '1946-03-01', '1946-04-01', '1946-05-01'], dtype='object', name='DATE')

--- reset_index() ---

         DATE  WTISPLC
0  1946-01-01     1.17
1  1946-02-01     1.17
2  1946-03-01     1.17
3  1946-04-01     1.27
4  1946-05-01     1.27
---
Index(['DATE', 'WTISPLC'], dtype='object')
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

When you use `index_col=0` then `df.index` shows

```
Index(['1946-01-01', '1946-02-01', '1946-03-01', '1946-04-01', '1946-05-01'], dtype='object', name='DATE')
```

instead of

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```